Why don't `union`s trigger constructors?
For this code:
struct Vec2 {
  float x,y;
  Vec2():x(0),y(0) {
    printf( "Construct Vec2 %f %f\n",x,y );
  }
};
struct Rectangle {
  union {
    struct { float x,y; };
    Vec2 pos;
  };
  union {
    struct { float w,h; };
    Vec2 size;
  };

  Rectangle(){
    printf( "construct Rectangle %f %f %f %f\n", x,y,w,h );
  }
}

int main() {
  
  Rectangle r;

}

I was very surprised to learn that the default constructors for Vec2 are not triggered for the Vec2s that are inside the unions inside the Rectangle
I was very surprised by that wonder why that is?

Think:  which constructor should be triggered and how would the compiler know this?

Any time you have a union containing 1 or more non-trivial types, especially types with constructors, you should consider using std::variant instead.

You probably hope to use x, y, w, h as aliases for Vec2 members. While it may work in practice, this is Undefined Behavior.

@RemyLebeau A std::variant is great for when the object should hold one type or the other, but the intention here is just to alias Rectangle::x to Rectangle::pos.x, Rectangle::w to Rectangle::size.x

@Eugene Could you cite something that says using a union this way is ub?

Anonymous structs aren't in the C++ standard, so the program technically has UB before you even run it.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union: "It is undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written. Many compilers implement, as a non-standard language extension, the ability to read inactive members of a union."

@BrianBi I think they are allowed as an MSVC++ extension, so I don't think the program behavior is completely unpredictable. I know that C11 did allow them

More proof that C and C++ are different languages.

@bobobobo Being allowed as a msvc extension doesn't make it valid C++. If you strive to write portable code (which I think people should), then language extensions are utter garbage (in most cases - there are always exceptions).

"I was very surprised by that wonder why that is?" -- I am very surprised that someone would think that a union -- which can hold only one type at a time -- would by default construct all of its possible types. (Yes, I am filling in some blanks, perhaps unfairly, but if you don't like that, you shouldn't have left the blanks in your explanation.)

The compiler generated default constructor, default constructs the first member with an accessible default constructor. If there's an trivial class, then it won't be default constructed. Anyhow with unions programmer must act very accurately. Keeping track of active member is not easy. That's why std::variant was added to C++; it always keeps track of the active member. Don't do unions.

To fix this, you'd have to manually invoke the Vec2 constructors from the Rectangle constructor:
Rectangle():pos(),size(){
  printf( "construct Rectangle %f %f %f %f\n", x,y,w,h );
}

Very surprising!

Here is another way to do this same thing, by aliasing some x, y, w, h float variables to the struct vars:
struct RectF {
  Vec2 pos;
  Vec2 size;
  
  float &x = pos.x;
  float &y = pos.y;
  float &w = size.x;
  float &h = size.y;
  
  RectF(){
    printf( "construct RectF %f %f %f %f\n", x,y,w,h  );
  }
};




Be a bit cautious here. Since you cannot redirect a reference after initialization, it is now impossible to assign instances of RectF without writing a custom assignment operator.

Since pos isn't a pointer, I don't think there would be a problem there. &x of one instance should just stay nailed to pos.x. It won't ever dangle since &x would deallocate before pos does. &x should just be completely synonymous with pos.x

Demonstration of what I'm talking about: https://godbolt.org/z/3vr5obPTn x cannot be repointed. It doesn't have to be repointed in this case, but the compiler doesn't know that.
